# Проблема при выводе JSON данных в append

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

Переписываю запрос под `XmlHttpRequest`. Возникла проблема вывода результата в `append`. Раньше все было на ajax и работало.

Вот то, что есть:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users', false);
xhr.send();
var apidata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
$('#listusers').append("<div class='user anim aslide' data-json='" + JSON.stringify(apidata) + "'>" + apidata['login'] + "</div>");
```

Проблема в том что на выходе (`apidata['login']`) имеем `undefined`.

Comment: может `apidata.login`?

Comment: @cyadvert - должно быть то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.github.com/users - возвращает массив:

```
console.log(apidata[0]['login']);
```